# How can I access an XML file in the root project directory in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

This seems like an extremely simple thing to do, but I have not been able to find an answer to my question specifically. I have an ASP.NET website project, and I'm trying to simply load an XML file to process some data. See the code below.

```
var XmlData = XDocument.Load("TheXMLFile.xml");
```

This line of code is giving me the following error: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code Message=Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\TheXMLFile.xml'`.
First of all, the path given above isn't even where the file is anyway. The project file structure looks like this:

```
MyProject
    .
    .
    .
     TheXMLFile
```

I am clueless as to why it can't find the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: is the xml file deployed with the site? if so try `Server.MapPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually `Server.MapPath("TheXMLFile.xml")`. Thanks to everyone for the advice. Nobody posted this exact solution, but it was because of the other posts that I got to this answer.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, if this is the correct solution.

Comment: I will. I have to wait 2 days, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TheXMLFile.xml")
```

Comment: obviosly - var XmlData = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TheXMLFile.xml"));

Answer (score -1):

What you want to use is `var XmlData = XDocument.Load("~\TheXMLFile.xml");`

But since XDocument.Load doesnt know about `~` you need to first convert path to full path ( see @aloneguid answer ) and then load

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TheXMLFile.xml");
var XmlData = XDocument.Load(path);
```